# Unable to install NVIDIA GPU drivers on Xenial

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have an ASUS K55VM and I've been trying to install NVDIA GPU drivers on my laptop, but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

These are the packages I've installed:

```
$:/usr/sbin# dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep bumb
bumblebee                       install
bumblebee-nvidia                install
```

```
$:/usr/sbin# dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep nvidia
bumblebee-nvidia                install
nvidia-304                      install
nvidia-current                  install
nvidia-opencl-icd-304           install
nvidia-settings                 install
```

This is my graphic card configuration:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 630M]
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.3 drivers: vesa,intel (unloaded: fbdev)
           tty size: 168x43 Advanced Data: N/A for root
```

This is the output of `optirun`:

```
$:/usr/sbin# optirun -vvv glxgears
[ 4340.857497] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 4340.857876] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 4340.858090] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 4340.858118] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 4340.858123] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 4340.858129] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 4340.858133] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
[ 4340.858139] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 4340.858143] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 4340.858148] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 4340.858168] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 4340.858183] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 4340.858255] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[ 4340.864799] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) 

[ 4340.864836] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) 

[ 4340.864855] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 4340.864896] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 4340.864908] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

The following are the relevant `bumblebee` configuration settings:

```
...
Driver=nvidia
...
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia_304
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Comment: Why do you install legacy drivers for GT630M? `nvidia-304` does not support your adapter. Install `nvidia-361`.

Answer (score 0):

You install wrong drivers. Remove the legacy driver and install the correct driver this way:

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo apt install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```

Reboot.

Comment: This did not work. When I booted back after doing this, my screen kept blinking.

Comment: Where there any errors when you installed?

Comment: No, there were no errors. 
My problem was solved after I installed the proprietary drivers from additional drivers.